# How to access scene functions from other scenes with react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, react-native-router-flux

I have a feeling that I might be going in the wrong direction,
Because it cant possibly be this unintuitive
But then again, I can be really dumb.
So my question is:
How can I access scene functions when I'm not in the scene currently.
My example:

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Add from './components/Add';
import {Router, Scene, Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
        <Scene key='root'>
        <Scene key='home' component={Home} title='Home' rightButtonImage={require('./assets/plus.png')} onRight={() => {Actions.add()}}/>
        <Scene key='add' component={Add} title='Add'/>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Image, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import ScrollCompanyIndex from './ScollCompanyIndex';

var {screenHeight, screenWidth} = Dimensions.get('window');

var companies = require('./companies.json');
var companiesString = JSON.stringify(companies);
var comapniesJson = JSON.parse(companiesString.toString());
var companyList = [];

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        companyList = [];
        comapniesJson.companies.forEach(element => {
            companyList.push(element);
        });
    }

    rerenderComponent() {
        console.log('Rerendering the component');

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
                <ScrollView>
                    {
                        companyList.map((item, key) => (
                            <ScrollCompanyIndex key={key} imageUri={'https://picsum.photos/' + (129 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) + '/' + (129 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))} companyName={item.name} companyAddress={item.address + ', ' + item.city}/>
                        ))
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

**Add.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class Add extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Button onPress={gallaryButtonPressed} title='Camera / Gallery Button' color='#841584'/>
                <Button onPress={addButton} title='Add button' color='#841584'/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function gallaryButtonPressed() {

}

function addButton() {

}

export default Add;
```

So. How can i access for example, The function **rerenderComponent()** that is found in **Home.js**,
when I click the **"Add button"** button that is found in **Add.js** *that is currently linked to the function addButton() but nvm that*,

Thank you very much :3

Comment: did any of the below solutions worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Actions.key()` can accept an object as the props being passed to the child scene, you can try to route to the *add* scene from the *home* scene where you can pass the `rerenderComponent()` as a callback function.

So that it will be like:

**Home.js**

```js
toAdd() {
    Actions.add({ rerenderComponent: this.rerenderComponent.bind(this) })
}
```

**Add.js**

```jsx
<Button onPress={this.props.rerenderComponent} title='Add button' color='#841584'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked a good question, i was also wondering about this but then i found the solution.

**App.js**

`<Scene key='home' component={Home} title='Home' rightButtonImage=require('./assets/plus.png')} onRight={() => {}} />`

**Home.js**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        companyList = [];
        comapniesJson.companies.forEach(element => {
            companyList.push(element);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
     this.props.navigation.setParams({
     onRight: this.addButton         
     });
    }

    addButton = () => {
      return <Button onPress={() => Actions.Something()} title='Add button' color='#841584'/>;
    }
```

Similarly you can access `rerenderComponent` function.